# Ubuntu Installer didn't ask which drive to install to

Tags: installation

I tried installing Ubuntu 12.10 to my Windows desktop for a dual boot system. I used YUMI so I could install it from a flash drive. My problem is that the installer never asked which drive I wanted to install to. After asking about my language, time zone, and keyboard, it just started copying files. I freaked out when I heard it thrashing my hard drive - I thought it was overwriting my copy of Windows, so I forced my computer to shut down while it was working.

After rebooting back into Windows, I see that it deleted everything on my D drive (storage and backup drive) and was apparently installing Ubuntu onto it. I lost a lot of stuff because the installer never asked where I wanted to install Ubuntu (I have multiple hard drives and partitions).

How can I get the installer to check with me before deciding for itself where it's going to install?

Comment: hope data recovery may help you.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: possibly a bug or you performed a double click (may be mouse problem) so quick that it selected the default options and starts installing.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose where to install Ubuntu and specify partitions manually by choosing **Something else** in the **Installation type** screen.

[image: ubuntu installation type]

Comment: But the thing is, the OP said that this selection screen didn't come up. So how would this solve the problem?

Comment: @nerof61 OP only said it didn't ask where to install... and this this screen doesn't ask (as the next one does). I think it is fairly common mistake to ignore this screen.